# Drag and drop a UIImageView that is on a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uiimageview, uitouch

I am having a hard time finding good example of drag and drop with ios.  I do have a working code that does drag and drop but it is not working as expected.  The drag does not happen immediately after the touch and drag.  I have to touch the image, load a dragImage to the main VC and then retouch and drag the dragImage for it to work.

some how the new added UIImageView (dragImage) does not receive touch events or pick up touch events when it does not receive the initial touchBegin event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `touchesBegan` as your way of handling drag/drop that might be the first stumbling block. It's probably going to be much easier for you to use the various `UIGestureRecognizers` that are provided in iOS 4.0 and greater (unless you have a specific reason for supporting iOS 3).

With gesture recognizers you can simply attach one to your `UIImageView` and have the view change its center point to where the touch is whenever your recognizer is triggered. If you're not keen on using gesture recognizers perhaps you could provide some of your existing code so we can get a feeling for what's going on here.

Comment: I tried both methods. Even when using UIGestureRecognizers,  The UIImageView that is loaded during the initial touch does not fire the correct event the first time.

Comment: Just in case, you are setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for your image views - the default for images is `NO`...